# c# Unity3D Special Falldamage

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i am coding in Unity3D and i need to make so that i loose half of my maximum health which is 100 if my jump is over 1.533287.

My problem is that my player can double jump and is supposed to land on platforms higher than the start place of the jump.

```
 }
   void Start()
{

}
public int doubleJump = 0;
public float speed = 6.0F;
public float jumpSpeed = 8.0F;
public float gravity = 20.0F;
public int health = 100;
public float maxHeight;
public float height;
public int maxHealth = 100;

private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    CharacterController controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    if (controller.isGrounded)
    {
        moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, 
        Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
        moveDirection *= speed;
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
        }
        doubleJump = 0;
    }
    if (!controller.isGrounded)
    {
        if (doubleJump == 0)
        {
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
            {
            moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;

            doubleJump = 1;
            }
        }

    }
    if (maxHeight < height) //This sets the maximum height
    {
        maxHeight = height;
    }
    height = transform.position.y;

    moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: You have not provided a question to your problem.

Comment: What's the actual issue?  Is the player being injured if they make a safe jump upward of the same distance at which you assert fall damage?  If so, all you need to do is confirm the start value on the appropriate axis is greater than the end value if the distance is past your threshold.

Answer (score 1):

I would modify your code to use your player's rigidbody.

For example... if the player's velocity.y is in the positives, then he's moving upwards.
If the player's velocity.y is in the negatives, then it means they are falling.

Make it so that if the velocity.y is below a certain value, then they take fall damage. 
That way if you player doubles jumps towards a platform, when they land the velocity.y might be a small negative number. However if they jumped off of that high platform, they'd have a longer fall time which means a larger negative velocity.

Here's an example, although I don't know what scale you're working in so the numbers may be inaccurate for your scene.

Your player double jumps towards a platform, and when they reach their maximum height their velocity.y is now equal to 0.
As they start falling, velocity.y dips into the negatives. This means that when your player lands, they'll have a negative velocity. Let's say -5.

You can make your code say something similar to

```
if(playerRigidBody.velocity.y <= -10)
{
   FallDamage();
}
```

So if your player has been falling for a little while, they'd take fall damage. However since when they landed on your platform at a velocity of -5 they wouldn't take fall damage... and if they jump  off the platform and land on the ground below their velocity will more than likely be below -10 in the example.

Hopefully this helps you figure this out!